# adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and listview.invalidateViews not refreshing listview

Tags: android, listview

I have an application where the user will click on an item in the listview and either save, cancel, or delete the entry(this is done on a new activity that is started on the item click). so in the activity that is started on item click , after i click either button i call finish() to return to my previous activity and in this case the activity with the listview. However, if I do any change to the item in the list, the list is not changed at all. I tried using both .notifyDataSetChanged() and invalidateViews but neither of the two worked. Here is my code.

```
public class Flashcards_List extends ListActivity{

String[] All_Cards = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView listview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.flashcards_list);


    Flashcards Cards = new Flashcards(this);
    Cards.open();


    All_Cards = Cards.getAllFronts();


    listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listview.invalidateViews();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Flashcards_List.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, All_Cards);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


    String Specific_Card = All_Cards[position];

    /* Class to assist us in loading the activity */
    Class editClass = null;

    try {
        editClass = Class.forName("com.example.flashcards.Edit_Flashcard");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Bundle specificCard = new Bundle();
    specificCard.putString("card", Specific_Card);


    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Flashcards_List.this, editClass);
    ourIntent.putExtras(specificCard);//passing the bundle to the activity
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

This class edits the DB entry

```
public class Edit_Flashcard extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

String front_of_card = null;
Bundle bundle_received;

Button cancel, delete, save;
EditText front, back;

String[] card;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_flashcard);

    bundle_received = getIntent().getExtras();
    front_of_card = bundle_received.getString("card");//current card is the card that was clicked on
    Flashcards info = new Flashcards(this);
    info.open();
    card = info.getCard(front_of_card);
    info.close();

    initialize();
}

public void initialize(){

    front = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.front);
    back = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.back);
    front.setText(card[1]);
    back.setText(card[2]);

    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);

    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.cancel:
            super.finish();//finishes the activity, and returns to previous Activity
            break;

        case R.id.save:
            try{

                Flashcards update_entry = new Flashcards(this);
                update_entry.open();

                update_entry.updateEntry(card[0], front.getText().toString(), back.getText().toString());
                update_entry.close();
            }catch(Exception e){            

                String save_text = "The Flashcard could not be saved. Please try again.";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Edit_Flashcard.this, save_text, duration);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
            super.finish();
            break;

        case R.id.delete:
            try{

                Flashcards delete_entry = new Flashcards(this);
                delete_entry.open();

                delete_entry.deleteEntry(card[0]);

                delete_entry.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                /* set the value to NOT INSERTED */

                String delete_text = "The Flashcard could not be deleted. Please try again.";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Edit_Flashcard.this, delete_text, duration);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        super.finish();
            break;
    }/* end Switch */
}/* end onClick */
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you modifying your data?

Comment: Try to move `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` line before `startActivity(ourIntent);`.

Comment: Vishesh, I just added the class that tempers the DB entry.

Comment: Stan, I tried it and it did not work

Comment: @Angelov, if you actually change items in the popping up activity, then you should start it by means of `startActivityForResult` and provide event handler `onActivityResult`. In this handler you should call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Flashcards_List.this, editClass);
ourIntent.putExtras(specificCard);//passing the bundle to the activity
startActivity(ourIntent);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

`notifyDataSetChanged` is executed IMMEDIATELY after you call `startActivity()`, it doesn't block. Instead, you should load your data in `onResume()`, that way the latest data will always be shown when the activity comes back. Basically leave only the `setContentView()` in your `onCreate`.

Comment: Thank you so very much. Very quick and easy fix! :)

Comment: No problem. You might want to update your code to be a bit smarter and just update the adapter value in onResume, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Launch EditClass activity by startActivityForResult method. Implement onActivityResult method in the calling activity and in that method call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am sure that it will work but the person underneath you gave a quick fix. Thank you.